# Automation Error , Unspecified Error while creating charts in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am generatig a Pivot table and a 100 stacked column Chart by  VBA.

I want to Change the Y axis value from percentage to absolute numbers.

I recorded macros and used the below line.

> .Axes(xlValue).Select
>
> Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "Standard"

while, i am using this line, I get an run time error

> Automation error or unspecified error.

I researched and found there can be a Chance I am missing a reference, but i am struck which reference to add and how to sort this Problem. Below is the code i am using to generate Chart from Pivot.

```
Sub chart()

Dim sh As Shape
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set ptable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set ptr = ptable.TableRange1

Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
sh.Select

With ActiveChart

.SetSourceData ptr
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked100
.Axes(xlValues).Select 
selection.Ticketlabels.Numberformat =" Standard"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try skipping the selection step and fix your typo:  `.Axes(xlValues).Ticklabels.Numberformat =" Standard"`  (not Ticketlabels)

Comment: @tim Williams still the error is there.

Comment: I am not aware of this 'Standard' Number format. Perhaps you meant "General"

Comment: ya it was General when i did manually.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it should be `xlValue`, not `xlValues`.  And it looks like you have a space at the beginning of your specified format.  Try...

```
.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "Standard"
```